# display specific image to datagridview cells when condition meets

Tags: c#

I am trying to display an image to specific cells in datagridview but I can't. Any help? it returns the error  like system.drawing.... The code am using is this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToString(r.Cells[6].Value) == "Cancelled")
    {  
        Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Elias-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\FIDs Display\FIDs Display\bin\Debug\ET.PNG");

        r.Cells[6].Value = image;
        //r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

        r.Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific with *"but I can't"*. Does the image not show up, do you get an error message, does the cell simply show a string representing the type, etc. Also you should add a tag for WPF or WinForms.

Comment: You're gonna have to debug your code, set your breakpoint to the "== "Cancelled" part and see why it's not "Cancelled".

Comment: Is `r.Cells[6]` actually a `DataGridViewImageCell` or part of a  `DataGridViewImageColumn`??